# How do I pass props in each blocks in Ssvelte

Tags: node.js, arrays, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm a bit confused with Svelte's props.
I have a component named `Assignment` which I will use in my `Board` component.
I wish to have a dynamic array prop in my `Assignment`'s {#each} block.

```
<script>
    export let array
</script>

<div {array} class="flex-column">
    <div class="row-item">
        <h4>Open</h4>
        {#each {array} as value}
            <div class="description">
                <p>{value.status}</p>
                <p>{value.name}</p>
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is my `Assignment` component

My wish is for me to able to do something like this:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <Assignment
        {myArray}
    />
    <Assignment
        {myArray2}
    />
</div>
```

With a new array in each component call. So I guess my question is: How do I pass a prop into a each block?

Kind regards

Comment: Is [this](https://svelte.dev/repl/5a1b86c4b87e4018a50954d71d7ee63a?version=3.53.1) what you're trying to do? Using the property in an `{#each}` block doesn't use braces around the value you are iterating over (so just `{#each array as value}`). And declaring a component with a property uses the property name (so `<Assignment array={myArray} />`).

Comment: Ah ofc! This fixed the issue  Forgot to declare the array when I called the component. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Desjardins is there any way to avoid [this](https://imgur.com/a/r4u9Zfc) shown in the DOM?
And by this, I mean the: array="object object........"

Comment: That's coming from the `{array}` you have on the `<div>` element. That's a shorthand property, the same as saying `array={array}`. `array` isn't a valid attribute for a div, but it tries to do it anyways, and the value is the actual string representation of your array. You don't need to set that attribute on the div itself, though, it's not doing anything there.

Comment: That makes alot of sense. You sir, are tonight's hero. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an [`{#each ...}` block](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each), you don't use braces around the value to iterate over; just `{#each array as value}` will do:

```
<script>
    export let array;
</script>

<div class="flex-column">
    <div class="row-item">
        <h4>Open</h4>
        {#each array as value}
            <div class="description">
                <p>{value.status}</p>
                <p>{value.name}</p>
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

In addition, you do not need to add an array property to your div element. `<div {array}>` is a shorthand property and is equivalent to `<div array={array}>`. `array` isn't a valid attribute for a regular div element, but Svelte doesn't know or care about that and will happily apply the `array` attribute to a div. Its value is just the string representation of an array of objects (`[object Object],[object Object]` as you can see in your screenshot). However, that's not actually doing anything in this case; the `{#each ...}` doesn't see that as a variable and just uses the component's variable anyways, so it can be removed.

---

Then in your Board component, you can declare the Assignment component multiple times with different array properties, but when declaring the property, you need the property name, as in `<Assignment array={myArray} />`:

```
<script>
    import Assignment from './Assignment.svelte';
    
    let myArray = [{
        status: 'status 1',
        name: 'name 1',
    }];
    
    let myArray2 = [{
        status: 'status 2',
        name: 'name 2',
    }];
</script>

<div class="flex-container">
    <Assignment
        array={myArray}
    />
    <Assignment
        array={myArray2}
    />
</div>
```

---

Further reading:

- [Declaring props](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/declaring-props)
- [Each blocks](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks)